# root cron job not running

Tags: backup, mysql, cron

I am trying to configure `automysqlbackup` to run via a cronjob to backup my dbs nightly.

When I execute `sudo automysqlbackup` from a terminal, the process executes as expected and creates the backup archives.

I then executed `sudo crontab -e` and added

```
0 2 * * * automysqlbackup
```

to the cron jobs.

This job does not run, and I can't find any error messages that might help. Any ideas why this job isn't executing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common problem with cron is that it runs with a minimal shell with minimal environmental variable.

Use the full path to `automysqlbackup`

If you do not know the full path, run `which automysqlbackup`